# Material-ui: automatic <Dialog /> display every hour

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

to display popups, I use the `<Dialog />` component from the [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/) library, please tell me how can I show this popup automatically every hour?

```
    <Dialog fullScreen onClose={this.hidePopup} open={this.state.popupShow === 'testPopup'}>
      <DialogTitle disableTypography className={styles.dialogTitle}>
        Title
        <button className={styles.dialogCloser} onClick={this.hidePopup}>
          <CloseIcon />
        </button>
      </DialogTitle>

      <DialogContent className={`${styles.testPopup}`}>
        <p>O-Yama Mania soba ipame luipamis: das sobolo vepe zodomeda poamal, od bogira aai 
           ta piape Piamoel od Vaoan! Zodacare, eca, od zodameranu! odo cicale Qaa Ili e-Ol 
           balazodareji, od aala tahilanu-os netaabe: daluga vaomesareji elonusa cape-mi-ali 
           varoesa cala homila;
        </p>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTimeout function in loop. It could set some variable in state like isTimeToShowDialog. And then render Dialog only if isTimeToShowDialog === true